# How to understand the ipv6 route table?

Tags: networking, ipv6, mobile-devices

I know the ipv4 route table, it has a default gateway, traffic does not match other rules will go into it. but when I look at the route table on my mobile phone, I am confused about the result, there are many default routes and lots of netif like `ipsec`,`pdp_ip0` and `pdp_ip1`.

```
Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                           Flags   Netif  
default                                 fe80::e903:5cea:17ea:fecb%pdp_ip0 UGcI    pdp_ip0
default                                 fe80::d419:a6c6:3bd9:d440%pdp_ip1 UGcI    pdp_ip1
default                                 fe80::%utun0                      UGcI    utun0  
default                                 fe80::%utun1                      UGcI    utun1  
default                                 2409:8800:8806:f6e7::             UGcI    ipsec0 
default                                 2409:8800:8806:f6e7::             UGcI    ipsec1 
default                                 fe80::%utun2                      UGcI    utun2  
default                                 fe80::%utun3                      UGcI    utun3  
default                                 fe80::%utun4                      UGcI    utun4  
default                                 fe80::%utun5                      UGcI    utun5  
::1                                     ::1                               UHL     lo0    
2409:8800:8806:f6e7::/64                link#5                            UC      pdp_ip1
2409:8800:8806:f6e7::/64                fe80::48e1:3a00:850:59d2%ipsec0   UcI     ipsec0 
2409:8800:8806:f6e7::/64                fe80::48e1:3a00:850:59d2%ipsec1   UcI     ipsec1 
2409:8800:8806:f6e7:100c:6165:5fde:7787 link#5                            UHL     lo0    
2409:8800:8806:f6e7:5c28:2082:17e4:277  link#5                            UHL     lo0    
2409:8900:1800:607a::/64                link#2                            UC      pdp_ip0
2409:8900:1800:607a:1cf2:fec:67df:c2ea  link#2                            UHL     lo0    
2409:8900:1800:607a:40bf:b6b5:7261:a1ab link#2                            UHL     lo0    
2409:8900:1800:607a:e447:87d7:9f7b:14f5 link#2                            UHLWI   pdp_ip0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                       UcI     lo0    
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                            UHLI    lo0    
fe80::%pdp_ip0/64                       link#2                            UCI     pdp_ip0
fe80::16:587b:857b:84b2%pdp_ip0         link#2                            UHLI    lo0    
fe80::e903:5cea:17ea:fecb%pdp_ip0       link#2                            UHLWIir pdp_ip0
fe80::%pdp_ip1/64                       link#5                            UCI     pdp_ip1
fe80::857:f045:b0e8:d05e%pdp_ip1        link#5                            UHLI    lo0    
fe80::d419:a6c6:3bd9:d440%pdp_ip1       link#5                            UHLWIir pdp_ip1
fe80::%en0/64                           link#8                            UCI     en0    
fe80::49:3845:ebeb:3445%en0             2:0:0:0:0:0                       UHLWI   en0  
...
...
...
... many more
```

My question is

1. when a connection comes, which `default` route it?
2. I know `pdp_ip` comes from the mobile, but why there are two `pdp_ip0` `pdp_ip1`?
3. I am not connecting to a vpn, why there is a netif named `ipsec`?
4. where is the `2:0:0:0:0:0`?
5. how to understand such a huge result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The default route of the one active interface is used.
2. I guess your phone has 2 sim slots
3. usually an inactive interface unless your VPN is up.
4. "2:0:0:0:0:0" is a HOST over the "enc" interface, tunnel or vpn
5. The interesting parts are "2409:8800:" a tunnel to somewhere in "China Telecom", hopefully inactive.

Comment: Thx. my phone has only 1 sim slot, it seems pdp_ip0 & 1 are all in use.